# Use 2,3,4,5 to get 26 using only + - * /

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Use 2,3,4,5 and + - * / only once each (it's not necessary to use all of them) to equal 26.
I know 2 answers, but there is a 3rd (or more) :)

Answer (score 8):

One:

> 24 + 5 - 3

Two:

> 25 + 4 - 3

Comment: thank you! This was the 2 I knew, but I figured out the 3rd :)

Comment: @Consultant If concatenation is available to make “25”, this should also be legal: 2 concat (5+4-3).

Answer (score 8):

So I figured out the 3<sup>rd</sup> one I did not know :)

> $(3/2+5)\times 4=26$

Comment: What happened to spoiler?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of cheating leads me to:

> $5^2 +(4-3)=26 $

A second answer is:

> $5*(3*2)-4$

Comment: the second answer is not good, because it contains 2 multiplications. thank you :)